# Converting DATUM WGS84 coordinates for google map v3 JS Latlng Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps, wgs84

I am trying to convert the following to work with the Google maps v3 JS api.

N37 10.320 W122 13.357

How do I convert this to work with the LatLng Object?

I was expecting it to be two decimals, either positive or negative.

Thanks!

Comment: Also just to note: When I type in the coords above into google maps. It will find the point on their site, however it looks like the lat/lng is a bit different from the example above. 37.172269,-122.222149. I just want to be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's just a matter of converting degree-minutes to decimals. The coordinates above mean 37 degrees + 10.320 minutes. 60 minutes make one degree so you should be getting:

```
lat = degrees + minutes/60
```

In your example

```
37.172269 = 37 + 10.320/60
```

The N/S E/W translate to the sign of the coordinate. I guess North and East mean positive signs, South and West mean negative.